# ASP session variables leak

Tags: session, iis, asp-classic

How can i look every user session variable on IIS Application Server.
This issue is to find a biggest session variable on my application to find a leak because my session timeout requirement is too high.

Answer (score 2):

```
for each x in session.Contents 
  Response.Write x & session.Contents (x) 
next
```

You could have googled it.

Comment: Thanks my friend but you missunderstood look it "every user session variable"